# Setting SelectedItem of combo box in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, relaycommand

I have a combo box, selectionchanged event of combo box attached with its respective command and upon changing the selected item(from the drop down list) command is firing as expected but not when I set the selected item from the code.

This is some code that I have tried

```
        Projects.Add(new Project { ProjectName = "Project 1" });
        Projects.Add(new Project { ProjectName = "Project 2" });
        Projects.Add(new Project { ProjectName = "Project 3" });
        Projects.Add(new Project { ProjectName = "Project 4" });  

        SelectedProject = Projects[0]; // I am expecting selection changed command execution here

   ICommand _projectSelectionChangedCommand;
   public ICommand ProjectSelectionChangedCommand
   {
     get
     {
       return _projectSelectionChangedCommand ?? (_projectSelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(ProjectSelection));
     }
   }

 ObservableCollection<Project> _projects;
        public ObservableCollection<Project> Projects
        {
            get { return _projects; }
            set
            {
                _projects = value;


      NotifyPropertyChanged("Projects");
                }
            }

 public Project SelectedProject
        {
            get { return _selectedProject; }
            set
            {
                _selectedProject = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedProject");
            }
        }
```

and my xaml is this

```
   <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" DisplayMemberPath="ProjectName" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProjectSelectionChangedCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: how does your SelectedProject property look like?

Comment: @d.moncada I have updated the question with SelectedProject property

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use [Mode=TwoWay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode.aspx) in your SelectedItem Binding, else there is no guarantee that the selected item will change.

Also, be aware that trying to explicitly set a value not present in the Items available to the ComboBox will result in it instead setting a null. Attempting to manually set a null has additional oddities in behavior, indicating the underlying system uses a null value in between sets to actual values.

Comment: I am setting it like SelectedProject=Project[0]. So there is no way this could set value that is not present in the itemssource of combobox. But not working even with Mode=TwoWay.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your ComboBox has `TwoWay` binding set for SelectedItem, as well as `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`

```
   <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" 
             DisplayMemberPath="ProjectName"  
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProjectSelectionChangedCommand}"></i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a vague recollection that SelectedProject has to be set to a valid instance before the binding is created, if it's null then the binding winds up permanently broken in the direction from data context to view.

Comment: SelectedProject=Projects[0], so no doubt about the correct value being set.